# How to reuse the same Redux Saga for multiple React components with their own state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

This is a bit of a lengthy one to explain. As briefly as possible: I have two components, `Employees` and `AddEmployee` - these are both attached to the routes `/employees` and `employees/add` respectively. A link from the `Employee` component will push `employees/add` to BrowserHistory, and vice versa (the `AddEmployee` component will also push `/employees` if the form is successfully submitted, or if the user clicks 'cancel').

If I navigate to `/employees`, the component works fine. If I click to navigate to `/employees/add`, *that* component works fine. If I click 'cancel' or submit the form to redirect back to `/employees`... the component breaks.

Through much debugging I've determined that this is because redux state for `AddEmployee` is persisting through to `Employee`. My guess would be this is because they both make use of the same saga. I've written a single `get` Redux saga to handle requests to the remote API. `Employees` obviously uses the `get` saga to retrieve all users, while `AddEmployee` uses the `get` saga to retrieve possible locations to assign the user to.

When `Employees` is loaded, the state of the `apiGet` saga contains the retrieved employees. When `AddEmployee` is loaded, the state of the `apiGet` saga contains the retrieved locations. When you then navigate *back* to `Employees`, the state of the `apiGet` saga *still* contains the retrieved locations and it does not run again to load the employees again.

How can I solve this?

I've done my best to condense the code below to the relevant portions.

The `get` Saga:

```
function getApi(endpoint, token) {
    return fetch(apiUrl + endpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).then(handleApiErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch((error) => {throw error})
}

function* apiGetFlow(endpoint) {
    let response, token
    try {
        token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        token = JSON.parse(token)

        response = yield call(getApi, endpoint, token)

        yield put({ type: CLIENT_GET_SUCCESS, response: response })

    } catch(error) {
        ...
    }

    return response
}

function* apiGetWatcher() {
    while(true) {
        const { endpoint } = yield take(CLIENT_GET_REQUESTING)
        const task = yield fork(apiGetFlow, endpoint)
    }
}

export default apiGetWatcher
```

The `Employees` component:

```
class Employees extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.usersGet()
    }

    usersGet() {
        this.props.apiGetRequest('users')
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.apiGet,
    }
}

const connected = connect(mapStateToProps, { apiGetRequest })(Employees)

export default connected
```

The `AddEmployee` component:

```
class AddEmployeeForm extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.locationsGet()
    }

    locationsGet() {
        this.props.apiGetRequest('locations')
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        locations: state.apiGet,
        save: state.apiPost,
    }
}

const formed = reduxForm({
    form: 'addemployee',
})(AddEmployeeForm)

const connected = connect(mapStateToProps, { apiGetRequest, apiPostRequest })(formed)

export default connected
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its because your React components aren't unmounting.  It looks like the components fire their api requests from inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Say you start at `/employees/`, the `Employees` component mounts and dispatches the api request for users.

When you navigate to `/employees/add`, the `AddEmployeeForm` component mounts and dispatches the api request for locations.

When you press back, and your now back to `/employees`, the `Employees` component *has already mounted*.  Therefore it doesn't fire the request again for 'users'.

You can verify if this is the problem by implementing `componentWillUnmount` method in each component with a console.log.

That being said, in my opinion, you should not be sharing the `state.apiGet` reducer between components that expect the data to be completely different.  Different data should state maintained in their our reducers.

Say you refactored your components to successfully dispatch the API request when going back and forth, and `state.apiGet` updates accordingly.  Is that really what you want?  Will the API response be different every time the user presses forward and back?  Also, there will be lag from the api request and `state.apiGet` will have the wrong data initially until the request completes.

I would create a `users` reducer and a `locations` reducer.  Then create two sagas that wrap your `getApi` method and dispatch their specific actions.

For example:

```
function* getUsers(endpoint) {
    let response, token
    try {
        token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        token = JSON.parse(token)

        response = yield call(getApi, endpoint, token)

        yield put({ type: 'ADD_USERS', response: response })

    } catch(error) {
        ...
    }

    return response
}
```

And

```
function* getLocations(endpoint) {
    let response, token
    try {
        token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        token = JSON.parse(token)

        response = yield call(getApi, endpoint, token)

        yield put({ type: 'ADD_LOCATIONS', response: response })

    } catch(error) {
        ...
    }
    return response
}
```

In your components:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users,
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        locations: state.locations,
        save: state.apiPost,
    }
}
```

There are specifics in the [Official Redux](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) Docs about how to create separate reducers.